# creating bootstrap grid dynamically using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a row and an plus icon on top of the row using click event on a button. After that user can add or remove column inside of created row(and maximum four column inside the row) by clicking on plus icon and remove column using minus icon. 
    let's see the scenario:
    when we are clicking on plus icon:

```
if(class == row) then row will divide into two column;
if( class == col-sm-6) then row will divide into three column;
if(class == col-sm-4) then row will divide into four column;
if(class == col-sm-3) then all column will blank.
```

here is the codepen url:
    https://codepen.io/iqbalrehan/pen/bYpJPJ

Comment: Where is a problem?

Comment: problem is to when we click on minus icon then it will remove the column respectively such as - 
if(col-sm-6*2) then it will become row
if(col-sm-4*3) then row become 6*6
if(col-sm-3*4) then row become 4*4*4